# Silverlight module doesnt load with firefox (ASP.NET tag)

Tags: silverlight, firefox

I am using IE and firefox, this is the default statement that was created using a default asp.net tag.

This works perfectly fine with IE but with firefox, nothing is rendered.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Core.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="photoalbum.aspx.cs" Inherits="mkuk.photoalbum" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
    TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentLeft" runat="server">
    <asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/Static/silverlight/PhotoAlbum.xap"
        MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentRight" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

change Width="100%" Height="100%" to Width=600px Height= 800px. FF and IE7/IE8 cause problem with 100% values.

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050399/silverlight-2-does-not-render-content-on-ie7-ie8-firefox-3) -

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you installed FireFox after installing the Silverlight plugin?  Maybe you could uninstall Silverlight (plugin only) and reinstall.  You could also try loading this page in FireFox on multiple machines to see if its really a FireFox issue (shouldn't be).