# Silverlight 2 Does not render content on IE7 IE8 Firefox 3

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, silverlight-2.0, firefox-3

I have a very simple silverlight xaml page displays textbox and a button.

When i run my application on IE6 it works fine. But for IE7 IE8 and FF3 - it does not display any content. The page is rendering blank.

```
<div style="height: 100%; width:100%;">
<asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/test.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0"
Width="100%" Height="100%" HtmlAccess="Enabled" />
</div>
```

Does anyone has any idea what silverlight content is not rendering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer...! Just keeping the question / answer on StackOverflow so others can find the answer for similer question :

IE7 IE8 and FF3 does not accept value 100% as height or width or SL2 object. Change Height and Width to px value (for ex 800px) and that will solve the problem.

Thanks